# Where do I put media query code in rails for twitter bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Twitter-bootstrap and was difficulty with a form that was offset on tablet and phone views. I know the margin-left styling hat will correct each view but im not sure where I need to code the media queries. I tried it to code it in my bootstarp.css file, but it did not work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss`.

That's where you put those overrides.

If you don't have that file, you should add it.

I am assuming that you are using Rails 3 or 4, and are using these gems ofcourse:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
```

Comment: app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.

Comment: Mine doesnt have the .scss extension

Comment: I get an error after I try to add the .scss extension and does not allow my app to run .  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>                    Any suggestions ?